# flutter how to disable camera autofocus qr_code_scanner?

Tags: flutter, dart, barcode

I'm creating barcode scanning applications, how do I disable camera autofocus in my package qr_code_scanner? Or if it's possible how to disable camera autofocus in my app?
I want to disable auto-focus for improving performance.

```
     QRView(
              key: qrKey,
              onQRViewCreated: _onQRViewCreated,
            ),

void _onQRViewCreated(QRViewController controller) {
    this.controller = controller;
    controller.scannedDataStream.listen((scanData) {
      if (scanData != '') {
        HapticFeedback.mediumImpact();
        controller.pauseCamera();
        _invoiceScannerBloc.add(InvoiceScanEvent(
            id: widget.id, context: context, barcode: scanData.code!));
        Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
          controller.resumeCamera();
        });
      }
    });
  }
```